# How does Application Request Routing handle failed requests?

Tags: iis, arr

I've got a two-server rig that is load balanced using a round robin algorithm that IIS governs via Application Request Routing (and the URL rewrite feature).

I've reviewed some of the documentation available on MSDN and Technet, but I can't figure out how ARR will handle a failed request, aside from being able to detect it.

Does IIS 7.0's ARR retry the request or simply record the error somewhere?